# MVC controller to API controller

Tags: android, api, asp.net-mvc-4

I'am working in mvc. Can I link my mvc controller project to an api controller to make a web service?

I'am also working in Android so I have to connect the back end to using my mvc project. Is there any way to connect the android front end to back end using my mvc project?

Comment: Short answer yes, but there are so many ways to do it and variables in the methods, this seems too broad to answer well. You could either have your business logic in a class library shared by the MVC and API projects, or you could connect your MVC site to the deployed location of your API as a client (many options here).

Comment: Thank you Jason W for your comment ..